# convert a string to lower case in openshift yaml

Tags: docker, kubernetes, yaml, openshift, serverless-framework

In the openshift deployment config yaml file I've a parameter which is coming from my pipeline and it's a uppercase character and I want to convert that to lower case. Below are the ones which I've tried but didn't work.

```
uat-configmapfile-${SET}.lower()
```

```
uat-configmapfile-${lower(${SET})}
```

```
kind: Template
apiVersion: v1
parameters:
  - name: SERVICE_FULLNAME
    description: "The full name of the service e.g "
    required: true
  - name: SERVICE_VERSION
    description: "The version of this current service."
    required: true
  - name: VERSION
    description: "The version of this current service."
    required: true
  - name: REGISTRY
    description: "The registry to pull the docker image."
    required: true
  - name: APP_PROFILE
    description: "The profile environment variable to set in the oc pod."
    required: true
  - name: AMQ_SET
    description: "The amq set environment variable to set in the oc pod."
    required: true
metadata:
  name: ${SERVICE_FULLNAME}-${SERVICE_VERSION}
  labels:
    app: ${SERVICE_FULLNAME}-${SERVICE_VERSION}
    name: ${SERVICE_FULLNAME}-${SERVICE_VERSION}
objects:
 -
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: DeploymentConfig
  metadata:
     name: ${SERVICE_FULLNAME}-${SERVICE_VERSION}
     namespace: test
     labels:
       app: ${SERVICE_FULLNAME}-${SERVICE_VERSION}
       name: ${SERVICE_FULLNAME}-${SERVICE_VERSION}
  spec:
    replicas: 2
    selector:
      app: ${SERVICE_FULLNAME}-${SERVICE_VERSION}
      deploymentconfig: ${SERVICE_FULLNAME}-${SERVICE_VERSION}
    triggers:
     - type: "ConfigChange"
    strategy:
      type: Rolling
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: ${SERVICE_FULLNAME}-${SERVICE_VERSION}
          deploymentconfig: ${SERVICE_FULLNAME}-${SERVICE_VERSION}
      spec:
        containers:
          - env:
            - name: APP_PROFILE
              value: ${APP_PROFILE}
            - name: SET
              value: ${SET}
            image: ${REGISTRY}/${SERVICE_FULLNAME}:${VERSION}
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            name: ${SERVICE_FULLNAME}
            volumeMounts:
              - name: appconfig
                mountPath: "/tmp/test.properties"
                subPath: test_${SET}.properties               
            ports:
            -
              containerPort: 8443
              protocol: TCP
            resources:
              limits:
                cpu: 2000m
                memory: 4096Mi
              requests:
                cpu: 1000m
                memory: 2048Mi
            readinessProbe:
              tcpSocket:
                port: 8443
              initialDelaySeconds: 30
              timeoutSeconds: 2
              periodSeconds: 15
              successThreshold: 1
              failureThreshold: 3
            livenessProbe:
              tcpSocket:
                port: 8443
              initialDelaySeconds: 30
              timeoutSeconds: 2
              periodSeconds: 15
              successThreshold: 1
              failureThreshold: 6
            startupProbe:
              tcpSocket:
                port: 8443
              initialDelaySeconds: 30
              timeoutSeconds: 2
              periodSeconds: 15
              successThreshold: 1
              failureThreshold: 6
        volumes:
            - name: appconfig
              configMap:
                name: uat-configmapfile-${lower(${SET})}
```

Comment: Where did you find documentation suggesting that either of those examples would work? Looking through [the template documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.12/openshift_images/using-templates.html) I don't see anything that suggests OpenShift templates support any sort of transformation functions.

Comment: It's not there in the openshift template documentation. I've searched online and then I've found few solutions for serverless so tried the same here